# AJAX перезагружается

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, chat

Функция show по моей логике не должна перезагружать страницу а просто обновлятся  но нет она перезагрузается.
Как мне просто сделать так что бы она обновлялась без перезагрузки страницы?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
        <iframe name='chatWindow' id='chatWindow'frameborder="no" height="935" width="935" src='iframe.php'>Chat</iframe>
        </div>
    <br>    <input type='text' id="text" name='message'>
        <input type='button' id="button" value="send">

        <script>
        $(document).ready (function (
        ){  show(); setInterval("show()",100);

            $("#button").bind("click", function (){
            var message = $("#text").val();
              $.ajax ({
                  url: "iframe.php",
                  type: "POST",
                  data: {message},
                  dataType: "html"

              });  
            });  

            $("#button").bind("click", function (){
              $.ajax({
              url: "chat.html",
              cache: false,
              success: function(html){
                $("#content").html(html);
              }
              });                    
            });

            function show()  
            {  
                $.ajax({  
                    url: "chat.html",  
                    cache: false,  
                    success: function(html){  
                        $("#content").html(html);  
                    }  
                });  
            }  
        });
        </script>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "но она перезагрузается." - откуда Вы знаете? В коде, который Вы показали, нет ничего, что вело бы к перезагрузке страницы.

Comment: А-а-а, начинаю догадываться. У вас перезагружается страница во фрэйме?

Comment: @Igor show(); setInterval("show()",100);   перезагружает страницу мне

Comment: какую страницу? У Вас их две.

Comment: @Igor  iframe.php и chat.html   и оказыватся по нажатию на кнопку message тоже перезагружается страница

Comment: У Вас нет кнопки message. Страница chat.html не может перезаружаться.

Comment: @Igor да перепутал у меня одна там кнопка, без имени c id button

Comment: @Igor всмысле не может если она перезагружается

Comment: В коде, который Вы показали, нет ничего, что вело бы к перезагрузке страницы. Но я подозреваю, что мы говорим о разных вещах. Откуда Вы знаете, что страница перезагружается?

Comment: @Igor я наблюдаю это в браузере опера на странице chat.html

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте это

```
 $("#button").on("click", function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var message = $("#text").val();
      $.ajax ({
          url: "iframe.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {message},
          dataType: "html"

      });  
    });  

    $("#button").on("click", function (e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
      url: "chat.html",
      cache: false,
      success: function(html){
        $("#content").html(html);
      }
      });                    
    });
```